# Reputation reset to 1; what happened to my account?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I had created my account a month ago. I had asked few questions and got some answers to them.  Overall my reputation was 30. Today When I opened my account then I shocked to see it that My reputation was gone. And all question is

Question from SO

[Full question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425408/i-want-to-about-stack-overflow)

> Acutually i had created my account one months ago And I was posted few question and there were some answers of that questions but today I open my account then I see that All question is deleted and my reputation down also..So what happen with me tell me????

Comment: which account you are talking about ?

Comment: The same account but it show that you have to set as new user that's why i set it as new user..but problem was occured in the same account

Comment: your profile history says you have created your account today only. i think you might did some mistake in login and it has created new account for you.

Comment: But this the same account I don't know what happen with me but I am sad..

Comment: well the any mod may light in this matter, because i dont have that much privilege to see your actions

Comment: Ok@lucifer I am too much sad because i earned repu hardly and honestly..

Comment: Even now you posted on Meta (good), you still don't understand why the off topic question you linked to was deleted from Stack Overflow?

Comment: what was your previous user id?

Comment: Send an email to team@stackoverflow.com, they might be able to help you. I wasn't able to find another account with the email address on this one.

Comment: (@Null, given Google, it might have been http://stackoverflow.com/users/1414740/hiii)